# JQuery - add class to tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

How can I add new class to tooltip JQuery without deleting previous classes? I tried this:

```
$('.quality_1').tooltip({
     tooltipClass: "quality-normal"
});

$('.type_dmg_1').tooltip({
     tooltipClass: "physical-damage"
});
```

and if element has 2 classes - 'quality_1' and 'type_dmg_1' it adds only 'physical-damage' class. Is there an equivalent of tooltipClass, which not replace the previous classes?
I'm not interested in this solution:

```
$('.quality_1.type_dmg_1').tooltip({
     tooltipClass: "quality-normal quality-normal"
});
```

because in this case there are too many possibilities. How can I do it?
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Here please check:

```
 $("#type_dmg_1").addClass("yourclassname");
```

Comment: This adds a class to the element, not to the tooltip.